# Reordering a complex sentence without changing its meaning

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I came across this sentence while watching a TV show on time travel:

> I want you to go and see me **when** I was a sophomore in high school.

In this, the speaker is asking somebody to go back in time.

---

However, if I put the dependent clause at the start:

> When I was a sophomore in high school, I want you to go and see me.

The meaning has clearly changed by moving the dependent clause to the start, as it doesn't refer to time travel anymore - it now simply refers to a wish that the speaker had when he was in high school.

Is this expected or am I overanalyzing? I'm wondering if there is a way to reorder this complex sentence without changing its meaning.

Comment: Your second sentence would mean what you explained if it said "When I was a sophomore in high school, I *wanted* you to go and see me."

Comment: Ah, that settles it! Since the independent clause is in `present` tense, and the dependent clause is in `past` tense, the overall structure still refers to time travel. Thank you :)

Comment: @TusharRaj If you converted above comment to answer, I'd love to mark it best :)

Comment: Your second sentence would make sense in context—and if it were rephrased slightly. "When did you say you wanted me to see you?" "When I was a sophomore in high school—I want you to go and see me then."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I was a sophomore in high school, I want you to go and see me.

This sentence, while sounding ususual syntax-wise, doesn't really change the meaning. Compare it to the following pair that mirrors the structure but doesn't involve time travel:

> A: I should've opened a savings account when I was in college.
>
> B: When I was in college, I should've opened a savings account.

Notice the subtle change in emphasis brought about by B, which is somewhat inapplicable in your second sentence, which is why it sounds a little unusual. It can be hard for us to parse a sentence keeping a time-travel interpretation open, because it's something we do very rarely. That is why in fiction they generally take the simplest structure possible, unless a [deliberate confusion is desired](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irfgXDrCRLs) for comedic effects.

Your inference about expressing a wish would be accurate if the second sentence said:

> When I was a sophomore in high school, I *wanted* you to go and see me.